# What is the difference between BasicHttpsBinding and WsHttpBinding with Transport security?

Tags: .net, wshttpbinding

As BasicHttpsBinding is new at .net 4.5, I don't seem to be able to find much stuff around differences between the two.

Comment: Based on the name I assume one uses HTTPS as the transport and the other HTTP

Comment: I thought that Transport security uses https too

Comment: Only a comment.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.wshttpsecurity  The transport security for this binding is Secure Sockets Layer (SSL) over HTTP, or HTTPS.  I think SSL over HTTP mean WS is doing the SSL part.  Again only a comment.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Indeed the two bindings are very similar.  The only real difference is that to require HTTPS, the endpoint needed to be configured with a BasicHttpBinding in which you define the security mode as Transport (or any of the other valid enumerations).  With a BasicHttpsBinding on the endpoint, the security mode is defaulted to Transport and the client credential type is set to None.

So here was your configuration before WCF 4.5:

```
<system.serviceModel>
  <bindings>
    <basicHttpBinding>
      <binding name="Service.BasicHttp.BindingConfig">
        <security mode="Transport" />        
      </binding>
    </basicHttpBinding>
  </bindings>
  <services>
    <service name="ServiceImpl">
      <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="Service.BasicHttp.BindingConfig"
                name="IService.Http" contract="IService">
      </endpoint>
    </service>
  </services>
</system.serviceModel>
```

With WCF 4.5, the same configuration can be simplified to:

```
<system.serviceModel>
  <services>
    <service name="ServiceImpl">
      <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpsBinding" name="IService.Http" contract="IService">
  </endpoint>
</service>
  </services>
</system.serviceModel>
```

See [What’s new in WCF 4.5? BasicHttpsBinding](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/327259/Whats-New-in-WCF-BasicHttpsBinding) for additional detail.

Comment: Interesting. This answer compares basicHttpsBinding & basicHttpBinding but the original question title asks the difference between basicHttpsBinding and WSHttpBinding (WS=WebService).