# Configuration binding extension 'system.serviceModel/bindings/basicHttpsBinding' could not be found

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, wcf, web-config

I am getting this error when I try to navigate to my .svc file.  It appears that it's not finding my basicHttpsBinding; here's that section of my web.config:

```
<system.serviceModel>
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior>
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
<protocolMapping>
  <add binding="basicHttpsBinding" scheme="https"/>
</protocolMapping>
<serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="false" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true"/>
```

I tried searching through Google but any answers I could find didn't seem to apply to what I'm doing here.  Most of what I found talked about custom bindings, of which I don't think I have any.  I'm honestly not even close to sure what could be causing this error, so any help would be greatly appreciated.  If you need more information let me know and I'll add it.

Comment: I'm having the same issue. Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: What .NET version do you use? BasicHttpsBinding requires .NET 4.5

Comment: @slfan We're using .Net 4.0; what would you suggest I do?  Do I just need to remove that protocol mapping section?

Comment: I am using .net 4.0 as well and I tried removing that and it seems to be working now. Please post a answer so I can give you some rep for your help.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

`BasicHttpsBinding` is a new binding in .NET 4.5, therefore you cannot use it in a 4.0 application. Either you remove the protocolMapping or you use another binding such as `basicHttpBinding` or `wsHttpBinding`.

When you configure SSL in IIS, this should work as well.

Comment: so are you saying you only need bsicHttpBinding and ssl will still work?

Comment: @CoffeeAddict the two bindings are very similar. See this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14874529/what-is-the-difference-between-basichttpsbinding-and-wshttpbinding-with-transpor to understand the difference

Answer (score 19):

If you have a similar scenario as mine where the Visual Studio-generated `Web.config` has the following configs:

```
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
    <pages controlRenderingCompatibilityVersion="4.0" />
  </system.web>
```

... add `<httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />`

So that you now have

```
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
    <pages controlRenderingCompatibilityVersion="4.0" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" /> 
  </system.web>
```

I also went on to remove `<pages controlRenderingCompatibilityVersion="4.0" />` with no impact in my situation.

Comment: This answer is good for a .Net 4.5 app. It's not obvious why it should be necessary to do this, given that we've already said  targetFramework="4.5", but it really does seem to be the case that parts of configuration will still default to 4.0 unles we set the target version here as well as in `<compilation>`.

Comment: So obvious...  Might use this, too: <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.7" />

Answer (score 3):

Remove `protocolMapping` section from `web.config` and it will work.

Answer (score 0):

if you use framework 4.5 or up you can add below code to your web.config

The following attributes can be set on the  tag.

```
  <system.Web>
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.8" />
  </system.Web>
```

Answer (score -1):

On VS2022, I explicitly specified the targetFramework attribute, as below:

From this

```
<httpRuntime/>
```

To this

```
<httpRuntime targetFramework="4.8"/>
```

...and it works well!