# C# error wcf services

Tags: c#

I am trying to deploy an WCF, using Internet Information Service. I worked with visual studio 2015. But i got this error:

> Configuration binding extension 'system.serviceModel/bindings/true'
>   could not be found. Verify that this binding extension is properly
>   registered in system.serviceModel/extensions/bindingExtensions and
>   that it is spelled correctly.

```
My Web.config is the following:

<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>

  <appSettings>
    <add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="true" />
  </appSettings>


  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="false" targetFramework="4.5.2" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5.2"/>
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name="ClientWebS.UserService"
               behaviorConfiguration="mex">
        <endpoint address="UserService" binding="wsHttpBinding"
           contract="ClientWebS.IUserService"></endpoint>
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8080/"/>
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="mex">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetBinding="true"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
    <!--
        To browse web app root directory during debugging, set the value below to true.
        Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing web app folder information.
      -->
    <directoryBrowse enabled="true"/>
  </system.webServer>

</configuration>

Thanks for help!!
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Configuration binding extension 'system.serviceModel/bindings/basicHttpsBinding' could not be found](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18239749/configuration-binding-extension-system-servicemodel-bindings-basichttpsbinding)

Comment: I don't exactly understand what you are saying. Can you be a little bit more explicit? Thank you!

Comment: The question that you asked has already been asked and answered.

Comment: Thanks, I've seen that question, but I'm already using "wsHttpBinding"..